# mongoose.connect() - unable to pass argument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, localhost

I am beginner in nodejs and mongodb. I am using this tutorial  **[scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4)**
 to develop a **restful api**. 
 
I got stuck at '**connect to our database**' 
**mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:node@novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/Iganiq8o');**

I have installed mongodb at -  C:\mongodb 
Data directory path - C:\Users\mshubham\Desktop\Main01\data\db 
Project path (api) - C:\Users\mshubham\Desktop\Main01\testapi.js 
Schema path - C:\Users\mshubham\Desktop\Main01\app\models

But I cannot get api request at  **localhost:8080/api/bears** 
**Cannot GET /api/bears**

I have tried all following combinations -

- mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/app');
- mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/app/models');
- mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/data');
- mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/data/db');
- mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017');

[UPDATE] - 
testapi.js - http://pastebin.com/6xgqWsfu 
bear.js -

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 
var BearSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear',BearSchema);
```

Comment: That problem does not seem related to the mongoose connect. Please post some more code.

Comment: The *"Cannot GET..."* error is usually related to a lack of matching route

Answer (score 1):

The error `Cannot GET /api/bears` is not related mongodb connection, it means there is no `get` route for `/api/bears`, also I did not find this route in your codes posted in the link. Please add `get()` as bellow following the original link.

```
router.route('/bears')

    // create a bear (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/bears)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        ...

    })

    // get all the bears (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/bears)
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Bear.find(function(err, bears) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(bears);
        });
    });
```